# How can I install MPFI library in Windows?

Tags: cgal, mpfi

there!

I'd like to execute example program, Surface_reconstruction_points_3.

I think the program needs additionally 3rd library, MPFI.

So I downloaded the library from http://mpfi.gforge.inria.fr/.

And I unzipped it at proper folder and linked it to the system path.

After configurating the example program using cmake-gui,

I found some error message, 'Could NOT find MPFI (missing:  MPFI_LIBRARIES)'.

How can I install MPFI library in Window using visual studio 2008?

Comment: It might me easier to compile it with mingw. Since this is a C library, you should be able to use it from MSVC afterwards.

Comment: @user2301466, Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Since MPFI is a GNU library, it is completely supported on Windows.

CGAL provides this third-party libraries inside its installation, but Windows has its own replacement.

I installed this correctly with Visual Studio, but you need to uncheck those third-party libraries so CGAL won't mess with the own windows replacements.

Maybe doing this kind of installation isn't working well for all the sample codes inside the installation, but it works fine for development. I used CGAL without those third-libraries for Voronoi and 2D and 3D triangulation and it works fine.

For a clean installation, delete all you installed previously, make sure the new installation isn't messing with the bad previous installation.

**EDIT:**

About not using those optional libraries for Windows, I just received a similar mail through the CGAL mailing list and these could be the steps for newer versions of CGAL (>4.2):

You have to comment 3 lines in the CMake machinery:

- In CGAL-4.1/CMakeList.txt you have to comment:

  - `#list (INSERT CGAL_ESSENTIAL_3RD_PARTY_LIBRARIES 0 GMP MPFR)`
  - `#hide_variable(CGAL_ESSENTIAL_3RD_PARTY_LIBRARIES)`
- In  CGAL-4.1/cmake/modules/UseCGAL.cmake you have to comment:

  - `#use_essential_libs()`

Answer (score 0):

On the other hand, you can search on internet for precompiled versions of MPFI. For instance, you can find precompiled GMP, MPFR and MPFI for Windows on http://vegas.loria.fr/rs/ .